# Execute action after geocoding in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, geocoding, promise

I am using the [nodejs nominatim module](https://www.npmjs.org/package/nominatim) to geocode addresses that I got by using a crawler. I would like to persist the results when all addresses have been geocoded. How can I make sure that the `writeJsonToDisc` function is called only after all searches have been completed? Is it even possible to achieve this with the nominatim module?

```
var values = [];

var c = new Crawler({
 "callback":function(error,result,$) {

    $('selector').each(function(index, a){
      var venue = $(this).html()
      /*...*/
      search(name, street, city);
    }).promise().done(writeJsonToDisc);
  }
});


function search(name, street, city) {
  /*...*/
  nominatim.search({ q: query}, function(err, opts, results) {
    /*...*/
    values.push(reults);
  });
}
```

Comment: What package is `Crawler` from?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.org/package/crawler